# 'Where I should be' vs 'Where I am meant to be'

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality-in-context

Is there a difference between these

> 1. Where I should be.

and

> 2. Where I am meant to be.

?

---

Context: When you are going to fill the autobiography section on SE, it says 'Location' and it's supposed to write USA or something like that and I wanted to write one of the 2 above.

---

Which is sounds better and why?

Comment: Both #1 and #2 mean the same thing but #1 is much more colloquial. Most people wouldn't say #2 unless it's formal, but #1 can still be formal. If in your situation it is formal, #1 and #2 are both good and if it isn't I would say #1. (In my opinion, even if it is formal, I would still prefer #1.) Hope that helps you answer your question.

Comment: Neither is "better," but the meaning is slightly different.  #1 simply says, "I am in the place that is appropriate."  (Or, possibly, "I am in the place I was told to go.")  #2 is usually a subtle way of referencing a hidden purpose or plan.  The un-named planner may be a divine power, or just "destiny."  But either way there would be someone or something that "meant" for you to be there.

Comment: @JDM-GBG Thank you so much for your explanation, that's exactly what I was looking for. Now I know I should use #2 :)